# XSLT to remove duplicate node and attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

need to remove duplicate entry in the xml using XSLT1.0 , How can this be acheived ?

```
 Example : For below input xml , i need only unique image element

    <image source="marginal_links_orange.png"/>
     <image source="marginal_programme_home.png"/>
     <image source="marginal_programme_guide.png"/>
     <image source="marginal_links_orange.png"/>
     <image source="marginal_programme_home.png"/>

   Expected Output :

    <image source="marginal_links_orange.png"/>
    <image source="marginal_programme_home.png"/>
    <image source="marginal_programme_guide.png"/>
```

Comment: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//image[@source]"/>        
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="image[@source]">           
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::image[@source = current()/@source])">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>&#13;&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```